# How to revoke other applications permission in android with root access?

Tags: android, android-permissions, cyanogenmod, root-access

I am making an android application which could temporarily remove other application's permissions such as their access to contacts based on the security level of the network.

I do not want to go into the OS level and make changes there. 
I know this could be done through cyanogenmod using privacy guard. Is it possible my application could access privacy guard programmatically and revoke permissions from there?

I also know I could decompile other applications and add my own code such that when those applications access resources like contacts my app will get notified and could block that access. But this approach is not feasible for every application.

Moreover, what other ways are there to implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance.